# Tensorflow Neural Network for Binary Classicication; how do I use placeholder

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

Here is my code:

My target is a vector with shape(N,) which is a vector with only binary numbers

However, I'm running into compiling errors

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/Lai/Dropbox/PersonalProject/MachineLearningForSports/models/NeuralNetwork.py
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Lai/Dropbox/PersonalProject/MachineLearningForSports/models/NeuralNetwork.py", line 102, in <module>
    _, c = sess.run([optimizer,cost],feed_dict = {x:batch_x,y:batch_y})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 943, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'
```

Since my batch size is 100; I believe that the error is at when comparing my target to my predictions. The tf.placable seems make the prediction with N*2, although I'm sure. Any help ?? Thanks

```
import tensorflow as tf
import DataPrepare as dp
import numpy as np


def random_init(x,num_feature_1st,num_feature_2nd,num_class):
    W1 =  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_feature_1st,num_feature_2nd]))
    bias1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_feature_2nd]))
    W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_feature_2nd,num_class]))
    bias2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_class]))

    return [W1,bias1,W2,bias2]




def softsign(z):
    """The softsign function, applied elementwise."""
    return z / (1. + np.abs(z))




def multilayer_perceptron(x,num_feature_1st,num_feature_2nd,num_class):
    params = random_init(x,num_feature_1st,num_feature_2nd,num_class)
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,params[0]),params[1])
    layer_1 = softsign(layer_1)
    #layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1,params[2]),params[3])
    #output = tf.nn.softmax(layer_2)
    output = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_2)

    return output





def next_batch(num, dataX,dataY):
    idx = np.arange(0,len(dataX))
    np.random.shuffle(idx)
    idx = idx[0:num]
    dataX_shuffle = [dataX[i] for i in idx]
    dataY_shuffle = [dataY[i] for i in idx]
    dataX_shuffle = np.asarray(dataX_shuffle)
    dataY_shuffle = np.asarray(dataY_shuffle)
    return dataX_shuffle, dataY_shuffle




if __name__ == "__main__":
    #sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

    learning_rate = 0.001
    training_epochs = 10
    batch_size = 100
    display_step = 1
    num_feature_1st = 6
    num_feature_2nd = 500
    num_class = 2

    x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 6])
    y = tf.placeholder('float',[None,2])


    data = dp.dataPrepare(dp.datas,dp.path)
    trainX = data[0]
    testX = data[1]   # a matrix
    trainY = data[2] # a vector with binary number
    testY = data[3]
    params = random_init(x,num_feature_1st,num_feature_2nd,num_class)

    # construct model
    pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, num_feature_1st, num_feature_2nd, num_class)

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)





    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()



    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)




        #train
        for epoch in range(training_epochs):
            avg_cost = 0
            total_batch = int(len(trainX[:,0])/batch_size)

            for i in range(total_batch):
                batch_x, batch_y = next_batch(batch_size,trainX,trainY)

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer,cost],feed_dict = {x:batch_x,y:batch_y})

                avg_cost += c/total_batch

            if epoch % display_step ==0:
                print("Epoch: ", "%04d" % (epoch+1), " cost= ", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
        print("Optimization Finished!")
```

Comment: Where is your placeholder ? I don't see it

Comment: @eliasah below  the if __name__ == "__main__":

Comment: Please format your code This is not readable

Comment: @eliasah but the code looks fine from here; it looks similar to other post's code

Comment: @ElleryL The code is a bit messy. First, please reduce the number of empty lines, since you have around 5(??) in some places. This is not nice to read. Secondly, try to enable syntax highlighting by following these instructions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you execute a dynamic node from the computation graph - which is pretty much any node that is not an input - you need to specify all dependent variables. Think about this this way: If you had a mathematical function of the form
`y = f(x) = Ax + b` (for example)
and you wanted to evaluate that function, you need to specify `x` as well. You need not, however, specify `x` if you wanted to evaluate (i.e. read) the value of `A`, since `A` is known (at least in this context).

Consequently, you can evaluate (by passing it to `tf.Session.run(...)` the parameters of your network without specifying the inputs (`A` in the example above). You cannot, however, evaluate the output of your functions without specifying the inputs (in the example, you need to specify `x`).

As for your code, the following line will thus not work:
`print(sess.run(pred))`, since you ask the session to evaluate a function without specifying its inputs.

Comment: thanks for the reply; now I've delete print(sess.run(pred)); try to run it; however, I'm having a new compiler error says that "ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 2)' .  So should I change the target shape into (100,2) ?? but my target is a vector with only 1 or 0, how does this gonna work
"